# swiftで数値をKeyにもつJSONデータをパース

Tags: json, swift4

swift4を使い、以下で公開されているAPIを使ってJSONを取得しました
しかしKeyが数値で返されるのでどうやってパースしたら良いかわかりません。

https://cryptowatch.jp/docs/api

取得できるJSONデータの形式

```
{
  "result": {
    "60": [
      [1481634360, 782.14, 782.14, 781.13, 781.13, 1.92525],
      [1481634420, 782.02, 782.06, 781.94, 781.98, 2.37578],
      [1481634480, 781.39, 781.94, 781.15, 781.94, 1.68882]
    ]
  }
}
```

ここで欲しいのはkey”60”以下のデータなのですが、どのように取り出せば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「数値をKeyに持つ」とは言っても、正しく引用符で囲まれていますから正当なJSONデータということになります。`JSONSerialization`でも、Swift 4から登場した`Codable`でも読み込むことはできますが、タグでswift4が指定されていることでもあり、ここでは`Codable`を使った例を示しておきます。

「自分でここまではやったのだが、この部分がうまくできない」と言うのを(動かないコードでも良いので)コードを示して質問されると、より的確な回答をより早く得ることにつながります。今後ご質問を書かれる際にはご留意ください。

さて、リンク先に挙げられたAPIの解説によると、キーになりうる値は限られているようです。

> ```
> All periods supported:
>
>  Value    Label
>  ------   -----
>  60        1m
>  180       3m
>  300       5m
>  900       15m
>  1800      30m
>  3600      1h
>  7200      2h
>  14400     4h
>  21600     6h
>  43200     12h
>  86400     1d
>  259200    3d
>  604800    1w
> ```

まずはSwiftの識別子として有効な名前でそれらに対応するプロパティを持つ`struct`を定義します。同時にJSON中のKeyとそれらのプロパティを対応づけるために`CodingKeys`と言うものを一緒に宣言しておきます。

```
typealias ResultValues = [[Double]]
struct PeriodicResults: Codable {
    var p1m: ResultValues?
    var p3m: ResultValues?
    var p5m: ResultValues?
    var p15m: ResultValues?
    var p30m: ResultValues?
    var p1h: ResultValues?
    var p2h: ResultValues?
    var p4h: ResultValues?
    var p6h: ResultValues?
    var p12h: ResultValues?
    var p1d: ResultValues?
    var p3d: ResultValues?
    var p1w: ResultValues?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case p1m = "60" //<- `p1m`には、"60": ... に対応する値が入る
        case p3m = "180"
        case p5m = "300"
        case p15m = "900"
        case p30m = "1800"
        case p1h = "3600"
        case p2h = "7200"
        case p4h = "14400"
        case p6h = "21600"
        case p12h = "43200"
        case p1d = "86400"
        case p3d = "259200"
        case p1w = "604800"
    }
}
```

これを使って、結果全体を表す`struct`を作ると、こんな感じになります。テスト用のサンプルデータとともに示しておきます。

```
import Foundation

let jsonText = """
{
    "result": {
        "60": [
            [1481634360, 782.14, 782.14, 781.13, 781.13, 1.92525],
            [1481634420, 782.02, 782.06, 781.94, 781.98, 2.37578],
            [1481634480, 781.39, 781.94, 781.15, 781.94, 1.68882]
        ]
    }
}
"""
let jsonData = jsonText.data(using: .utf8)!


struct OHLCResult: Codable {
    var result: PeriodicResults
}

do {
    let ohlcResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(OHLCResult.self, from: jsonData)
    if let p1m = ohlcResult.result.p1m {
        for valueSet in p1m {
            print(valueSet)
        }
    } else {
        print("no data for \"60\"")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

出力:

> ```
> [1481634360.0, 782.13999999999999, 782.13999999999999, 781.13, 781.13, 1.9252499999999999]
> [1481634420.0, 782.01999999999998, 782.05999999999995, 781.94000000000005, 781.98000000000002, 2.3757799999999998]
> [1481634480.0, 781.38999999999999, 781.94000000000005, 781.14999999999998, 781.94000000000005, 1.68882]
> ```

(出力される値がJSON内の表現とは異なっていますが、これは`Double`を使う上で避けられません。ユーザに見せる情報を作る場合には必要に応じて書式化してください。)

---

なお、Keyになりうる値は実は他にもある、と言う場合には、`Dictionary`型を使った方がいいでしょう。こんな感じになります。

```
struct OHLCDicResult: Codable {
    var result: [String: ResultValues]
}

do {
    let ohlcDicResult = try JSONDecoder().decode(OHLCDicResult.self, from: jsonData)
    if let p1m = ohlcDicResult.result["60"] {   //<-辞書型なので[]を使って元のキーを文字列としてそのまま使う
        for valueSet in p1m {
            print(valueSet)
        }
    } else {
        print("no data for \"60\"")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

出力例は先ほどと全く同じになります。お好きな方をお試しください。